# SNMP - нет доступа через переменные MIB

Tags: linux, snmp

Есть экспериментальная установка, железяки в которой управляются по SNMP. Всё работало замечательно до тех пор, пока в один момент не рухнуло...

После непродолжительных разборок выяснил удивительную вещь:

- доступ по OID есть ко всем переменным MIB
- доступа по именам переменных нет.

Пример совершенно азбучный:

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Linux dtk58 4.4.0-142-generic
```

Т.е. по OID всё работает. Однако по имени переменной не получается:

```
~$ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost sysDescr.0
sysDescr.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysDescr)
```

Я перепробовал все возможные варианты:

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost sysDescr
$ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost system.sysDescr.0
$ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost system.sysDescr
```

Результат один и тот же - идентификатор первой переменной в OID не находится.
Причём, если записать так:

```
iso.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
```

То прокатывает. А если вот так:

```
iso.mgmt.1.2.1.1.1.0
```

То уже - нет. Файл */etc/snmp/snmp.conf* пустой. Файла *~/.snmp/snmp.conf* нет совсем. Но в каталоге *~/.snmp/* лежат текстовые файлы MIB устройств, с которыми я работаю. И всё было прекрасно. Доступ был и по OID и по именам.

Подозреваю, что во время очередного автообновления системы что-то обновилось так, что у меня всё рухнуло. Но вот - что?

Comment: Оказывается, если ЯВНО задать имя MIB, вот так *snmpget -v2c -c public localhost SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0*, то работает нормально. получается, что где-то накрылись какие-то умолчания...

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/16948262/

Comment: да, надо прописать мибы в конфиг или в командрую строку

Comment: Но вот про это: *The agent was looking for the mib files in "/usr/share/snmp/mibs/".* что-о нигде не написано... В man пишут, что в */etc/snmp/* и *~/.snmp/*. А вот про этот каталог - ни слова...

Comment: Проверил на Ubuntu и OpenSuse. Оказалось, что в разных местах !